# BIOS doesn't update the "Boot device options" list

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, hp-pavilion

I am having a problem with my Laptop booting into Windows.
**TL;DR**: The BIOS doesn't detect any connected devices as bootable, and the boot device options list contains entries that are not connected.

**Long story**:
I wanted to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch (it started getting laggy) and convert the disk to GPT in the process.
- I booted the installer USB in UEFI mode, erased the whole disk, converted to GPT, and installed Windows.
- The problem is that it didn't boot, but instead showed the "No bootable devices, press any key to refresh" message.
- I tried installing Ubuntu 18, but it gave a "General Input/Output error"when it came to the GRUB installation stage, and it also couldn't boot.
-  I reinstalled Windows 10 and pressed F9 (change boot device) while booting to manually select the hard disk and I see that the options list still shows the 2 bootable USBs I had previously booted from, but are not currently connected.
-  I removed the CMOS battery and the laptop battery for about 24 hours.
- All BIOS settings were reset except for this list.
- The only way I can boot Windows is by stopping boot (F9) and choosing `Boot From EFI File > Microsoft > Boot > bootx64.efi` (or something similar).
Lastly, I tried updating the BIOS once I booted into Windows using the utility provided by HP, but the installer fails about 25% in.

> What should I do to return my BIOS to normal behaviour?

**Edit - added screenshots**:

[The "No bootable device" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KPD9.jpg)
[Boot options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq8Sw.jpg). Here you can see 2 devices (Toshiba  USB and Seagate HDD) that I used to boot from previously, but are not currently connected. Newly connected devices are not listed.

**Edit 2**:
It is also worth noting that the laptop can't go into sleep or hibernate modes. It can sleep, but if I try to open it again it will crash (the same way as if you held the power button for 8 seconds). And if I choose hibernate, the screen would go blank for a few seconds and then get back to the log in screen as if I just locked it.

*Device: HP pavilion-15 p214ne

BIOS: Insyde F.36 (2/2/2015)*

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

- UEFI = On
- Secure Boot = Off
- Legacy Options = Enabled
- Boot Priority = Windows Boot Manager (EFI/GPT/Whatever it says)

But NOT Windows Boot Manager on Seagate UUID-Hopefullyyoudonthaveaseagate [Disk Name]

## Method 2

Bootrepair disk.

- Download YUMI UEFI **[NOT]** YUMI LEGACY  https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
- Use it to make BootRepair Live USB
- Boot into it and it will scan for boot and fix the errors. (Its automatic)

Comment: The first option isn't present (it is the default). The second can't be changed (and is Off). The 3rd is on. And boot priority didn't help at all.

Comment: I already tried the 2nd method. It didn't work. I think it fixes boot problems related to files on the HDD, not the BIOS. I believe my problem is in the BIOS. Anyways, here is the link to its repair info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4wDpzFbH3w/